# awk gensub regex backslash 0 and backslash 1 not Working

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk

The following code works:

```
// {
print gensub("[a-z][A-Z]”,"&","g")
}
```

But this does NOT:

```
// {
print gensub("[a-z][A-Z]","\0","g")
}
```

And Neither does this which is finally what I want to achieve:

```
// {
print gensub(“([a-z])([A-Z])",”\1 \2","g")
}
```

Why is this not working and how do I make this work. Aim of this script: names are given with surnames not separated by space and I need to separate them. The first character of name is a capital alphabet and I do not want a space before the first name. I can do this with setting the `FS` to `''` and checking each character but I want to learn gensub. I also don't find the use of gsub as it is giving me the number of matches and not the string after replacement.

Another possible solution but I do not know how to make this work is to set the target in gensub from `"g"` to `"2,3,4"` and such but I am not able to give more than one argument over here.

**Please don't suggest alternate solutions only how to make one of the above work**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using "smart quotes" (`”`) instead of real quotes (`"`) in places, and awk backreferences are `\\1`, etc., not just `\1`. Also the first arg to gensub is a regexp not a string so use regexp delimiters `/.../` not string delimiters `"..."` (that latter causes double parsing which has negative consequences - see the man page). Get rid of the `//`s as they do absolutely nothing but clutter up your code. Finally - use character classes `[[:lower:]]` and `[[:upper:]]` instead of ranges `[a-z]` and `[A-Z]` for portability and robustness.

```
$ echo 'EdMorton' | awk '{print gensub(/([[:lower:]])([[:upper:]])/,"\\1 \\2",1)}'
Ed Morton
```

Comment: how do I change smart quotes and real quotes? How did you get to know such stuff as \\ instead of \?

Comment: also the problem about supplying more than 1 targets to gensub. Can you solve this? I don't know what are you talking about getting rid of // ? will my code work without them?

Comment: gensub() doesn't take multiple targets (if I understand by that you mean the 3rd arg)  - it's one number or "g". Yes your code will work without empty regexps.